# Conditional removal of duplicates based on NA

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

I have a df with two columns: `SurveyID` and `Species`.

```
SurveyID=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3)
Species=c(NA,NA,"GRSH",NA,NA,NA,"RAZO","RAZO")
df=data.frame(cbind(SurveyID,Species))
```

I want to remove the duplicates under two conditions:
1. All duplicates with the same `survey ID` and `NA` `Species` are removed
2. Rows with the same survey ID that have a mix of `NA` and `Species` (eg."RAZO") only display the rows with species by removing rows with `NA` `Species`.

The product df should look like this:

```
df2=data.frame(cbind(SurveyID=c(1,2,3,3),Species=c("GRSH",NA,"RAZO","RAZO")))
```

I tried sub setting with conditions but this removed duplicated species and kept unwanted duplicated `SurveyID` rows with `NA` `Species`.

```
df1= unique(df)
df1=df1[!is.na(df1$Species) | is.na(df1$Species)&!duplicated(df1$SurveyID),]
```

Any suggestions? Also I am new to this so let me know if my question needs clarification/formatting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(SurveyID) %>%
   filter(all(is.na(Species)) & !duplicated(is.na(Species))|!is.na(Species))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   SurveyID [3]
#  SurveyID Species
#  <fct>    <fct>  
#1 1        GRSH   
#2 2        <NA>   
#3 3        RAZO   
#4 3        RAZO
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by filtering to all non-`NA` `Species` values and then joining to a table of all `SurveyIDs`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[!is.na(Species)
   ][df[, .(new = unique(SurveyID))], on = c('SurveyID' = 'new')]

#    SurveyID Species
# 1:        1    GRSH
# 2:        2    <NA>
# 3:        3    RAZO
# 4:        3    RAZO
```